# Radial Distortion Correction using Feature Points e.g. SIFT

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I need to calibrate a fish eye lens, mono-camera and for some reason I cannot use checkerboard or circular pattern.

My question is : Can I can use some features (e.g. SIFT, SURF) to calibrate (for radial distortion only) a mono-camera? OpenCV or MATLAB is no bar. (Condition : The scene will remain static and the camera will move.)

Comment: Yes. Was that all you wanted?

Comment: Yes. No more XY problem.